# Bootstrap vue selecting the object from a list of objects b-form-select

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Even though I got the solution to my problem I'm slightly unsatisfied with how it's solved. Is there a way to make this simpler? As in, ideally I would have similar html and the only thing I would do is make a call to api to get the teachers and immediately assign them to `this.teachers` instead of having to iterate through them to make an untyped array of some new object.

HTML:

```html
    <b-form-select 
        v-model="selectedTeacher"
        :options="teachers"
        value-field="teacher" //NOT teacher.id, I want the object itself
        text-field="teacher.name">
    </b-form-select>
```

JS

```js
    var dbTeachers: Teacher[] = await getTeachers();
    
    dbTeachers.forEach(teacher => {
        this.teachers.push(new Object({
            teacher: teacher ,
            name: teacher.name
        }));
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind the entire object to the `value` of an `<option>` tag. So instead of using the `options`  prop you would manually create the `<option>` using the `v-for` directive.

That way you'll get the entire object in the `<b-form-select>`'s v-model.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: null,
      options: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Mike Macdonald', age: 42 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Larsen Shaw', age: 27 },
        { id: 3, name: 'Jami Cord', age: 81 },
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-form-select v-model="selectedItem">
    <option :value="null" disabled>-- Please select an option --</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  </b-form-select>
  Selected option: {{ selectedItem }}
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks, this helped me to resolve the same issue.

Comment: u dont need add extra option as first just add to data option with id: null